# Issue with cref and color names, generally and in theorem environments

Tags: cross-referencing, color, theorems

I am trying to use `\cref` from the cleveref package with in a theorem environment.  I also want my theorem names colored, say red.  Now if one tries to use `\cref` within a colored environment, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[capitalize, nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{redthm}{{\color{red}Theorem}}

\begin{document}

\begin{redthm} \label{thm1} Assume ABC.  Then D.
\end{redthm}

{\color{red} \ref{thm1}}

\end{document}
```

I get the error

```
./tmp.tex:13: LaTeX Error: Undefined color 'RED'.
```

I might like a solution, but I could live with that: what I really want to do is use \cref with my "red theorem" environments.  E.g., replace the above `\cref` line with:

```
\begin{redthm} Under assumptions of \cref{thm1}, E.
\end{redthm}
```

This gives the same error, even though the body of the theorem is not actually colored.  So can someone give me a solution to one or both of the following?

1. How can we use `\cref` in a colored environment?
2. How can we make a theorem environment so the word "Theorem" is colored but there is no conflict with `\cref` within the body of the theorem.

(I would also be to happy to hear an explanation of why these errors happen, bearing in mind I don't know anything about the internals of tex or these packages.)

Comment: this is just a guess, as i'm not really familiar with the internals of some of these packages.  the option `capitalize` for `cleveref` looks suspicious.  there's no uppercasing in `amsthm`, but when something you think should be lowercase is reported as not working and the unrecognized string is showing in uppercase, something is changing it.  try defining a color `RED` (equivalent to `red`) and using that.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Hmm, it does seem to be `capitalize` that is causing problems, although I don't know why it's capitalizing this (or every letter, as it usually just capitalizes the first letter).

Comment: @Kimball: I assume, that the capitalizing breaks here due to `\color`, due to various expansions etc, such that the capitalizing is applied to the argument of `\color`, i.e. `red` → `RED`, which is then fed into `\color`, leading to the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's better to use `\protect\color{red}Theorem` here, since the `capitalize` option of `cleveref` sees `\color{red}` first, wrongly transforming it into `RED` colour, which isn't defined here. `\color` is a fragile command, so `\protect` prevents the 'breaking apart' here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{redthm}{\protect\color{red}Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{redthm} \label{thm1}  Under assumptions of \cref{thm1}
Assume ABC.  Then D.
\end{redthm}

{\color{red} \ref{thm1}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works.  I didn't know about `\protect`.  But I'll wait a bit to accept in case some other interesting answers pop up.